# Retaining the value of a variable even after the C program is closed and opened again

Tags: c

I want to save an integer variable, so that it can be retained even after the C program is restarted.

The way is to store it in a file.

But it is just an integer variable. In the file if I write 1000 first and replace it with 12, it saves as 1200, how can I delete the old value which was there in the file and write the new one?

Or some other way other than files exist?

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: Could you show the code you use to open the file. You can open for append or create new file (destroying the existing one in the process). It depends on parameters you pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `fopen` to open the file stream, use the `"w"` mode; this opens the file for writing and truncates it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to truncate the file before writing to it again, this will wipe the contents so you can write the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `\n` or some other control character to indicate the end of the number. You can use `fscanf` to read it back.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use the registry for tasks like this.  If using Windows.

Comment: GConf is the registry equivalent in Linux. But its available in GNOME environment. But there should be something that's GNOME/KDE or any desktop environment independent.